# tables joining with pivot table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5.8 and I have four tables:

clients: id|name|code

tasks: id|name

client_task: id|client_id|task_id

monthlies: id|client_id|task_id|exec_date

Where `clients` and `tasks` are in many to many relationship and `client_task` is the pivot table

The idea is that I want to create a table in html like this

```
-------------------------------------------
|#|client name|task 1|task 2|task 3|task 4|
-------------------------------------------
|1| client 1  |  ☐   |  ☐   |  /// |  /// |
-------------------------------------------
|2| client 2  | ///  |  ☐   |   ☐  |  ☑   |
-------------------------------------------
|3| client 3  |  ☐   |  ☑   |   ☑  |  /// |
-------------------------------------------
```

every month I get all the clients and all the tasks and if a client has a task I show a checkbox else I show an empty `td` and if I finish a task for a specific client I check this task and insert the `client_id`, `task_id` and current date `exec_date` into `monthlies` table.

I right this query:

```
$clients = DB::table('monthlies as m')
        ->rightJoin('client_task as clta', function ($join){
            $join->on('clta.client_id', '=', 'm.client_id')
                ->on('clta.task_id', '=', 'm.task_id')
                ->rightJoin('clients as cl', function ($join){
                    $join->on('clta.client_id', '=', 'cl.id')->where('cl.category',1);
                })
                ->Join('category_task as cata', function ($join){
                    $join->on('clta.task_id', '=', 'cata.task_id')
                        ->Join('categories as ca2', 'cata.category_id', '=', 'ca2.id')->where('ca2.type', 1)
                        ->rightJoin('tasks as ta', 'cata.task_id', '=', 'ta.id')->where('ta.period', 1);
                });

        })

        ->select('m.*', 'cl.id as client_id', 'cl.name as client_name', 'cl.code as client_code', 'cl.legal_form as client_legal_form', 'ta.id as task_id', 'ta.name as task_name', 'ta.type as task_type', 'ta.period as task_period')
        ->get();
```

with this code I get only clients/tasks presents in client_task table

The problem is that I want to show all clients or tasks even if the client has no task attached to and vice versa (not present in `client_task` pivot table).

Comment: I'm curious, why are you writing "raw" SQL queries with the query builder? If you have your relationships setup correctly you could simply do `Client::with('tasks')->get()` and then loop through the resultant `Eloquent\Collection`. Laravel will do all of this heavy lifting for you ;)

Comment: I have many clients and many tasks and I want to get all clients + all tasks + check if the Binary (client-task) exist, if not I will show an empty 'td' in 'datatable', if it exist I check if this binary exists in `monthlies` table, if it exist then it will shown as 'checked + disabled' checkbox if not it means than I didn't finish this task for this client and I will show a simple checkbox, so I want to get all of that in one query

Comment: I would still throughly recommend using `Eloquent` to do this, i'll try to post an answer which covers this but it may take me a minute!

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, This may require you to make some changes to your relationships but i think you will see the benefits!

---

**Pivot table attributes & Models**

If the only difference between your `client_task` and `monthlies` table is `exec_date`, why not combine the two tables into `client_task`?

You can add pivot table attributes to your relationships like so:

**Client.php**

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'client_task',`client_id`,'task_id')->withPivot(['exec_date']);
}
```

Now when you get a `Client`'s `Task`'s, you can get the exec_date by using the `pivot` attribute (`$task->pivot->exec_date`).

You can even go as far as making dedicated `Pivot` models as shown in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

---

**Relationship Existance**

You can determine whether a `Client` has a given `Task` using the `whereHas()` function.

```
Client::whereHas('tasks', function (Builder $query) use ($task) {
    $query->where('id', $task->id);
})->get();
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

---

**Templates**

Most of the code for controlling you table will be done in the blade view using simple template logic:

```
@foreach ($clients as $client)
    <tr>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <td>
            @if ($client->tasks->contains($task)) 
                 @if ($client->tasks->where('id', $task->id)->first()->pivot->exec_date)
                     ... checked checkbox ...
                 @else
                     ... unchecked checkbox ...
                 @endif
            @else
                ...
            @endif
        </td>
    @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Great!! thank you very much for this detailed answer, even if I found my self with two queries but it's ok and it did the work

Comment: No probs, glad i could help! On a side note, don't feel that you absolutely need to get it all done in a single query. Sometimes a single large query will actually take longer than several smaller ones, but this needs to be looked at on a case by case basis ;)